# T-sql: how to perform optimised Paging?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, pagination

I wrote the following code, it works fine, but it takes like 3 sec to complete if the table is containing a million record.  Is there a way to optimize the following code.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

DECLARE @Page_Size int;
DECLARE @Page_Number int;
DECLARE @Lower_Bound int;
DECLARE @Upper_Bound int;

SET @Page_Size = 30;
SET @Page_Number = 30000;
SET @Lower_Bound = (@Page_Number - 1) * @Page_Size;
--SET @Upper_Bound = @Page_Number * @Page_Size;


WITH Customers AS--(Row_Numbr, Record_Id, First_Name, 
        Middle_Name, Last_Name, Email, Telephone) AS 
(

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER 
         (ORDER BY Account.Customer.Record_Id) AS Row_Numbr, * 
    FROM Account.Customer 
)

SELECT top(@Page_Size) * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE Row_Numbr > @Lower_Bound-- 
    AND Row_Numbr <= @Upper_Bound -- This is suppose to be faster
--SELECT * FROM Customers 
--WHERE Row_Numbr > @Lower_Bound  
--   AND Row_Numbr <= @Upper_Bound
```

Comment: what does the execution plan say?

Comment: What indexes do you have? Can you post the create table script?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897436/row-number-over-not-fast-enough-with-large-result-set-any-good-solution

Comment: The primary key is Record_Id so it is the table index, The execution plan says "97% for clustered index scan", "2% for filtering".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, why `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;` ? This is a hard cold reset of the buffer pool. Unless you want to measure and tune your hard drives IO performance, nobody cares about the performance of a cold cache. This is **not** how your system will work. Caching pages in the buffer pool is *the* most critical performance aspect in databases, and you take that out. Its like showing up in a Ferrari without the engine and asking why is so slow. For performance measurements you should do exactly the **opposite**: run he query 4-5 times to warm up the cache, then measure.

Second, what is your table structure? Is the table `Account.Customer` table cluster index order by `Record_id`? If no, you will never get the performance you want, no matter how you express your T-SQL.

And last but not least, what system do you have? Does it have enough RAM to cache the entire database in memory? If no, buy more RAM. Are there other processes that compete for memory, like IIS/Asp? If yes, kick them out to their own server, you should n[ever ever run the database on the same host as the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401834/when-can-i-host-iis-and-sql-server-on-the-same-machine/1429038#1429038) if performance is important.

For an alternative fast paging consider keyset driven solutions:

```
/* moving up */
SELECT top(@Page_Size) * 
FROM Account.Customer  
WHERE Record_Id > @lastPageRecordId
ORDER BY Record_Id;

/* moving down */
SELECT top(@Page_Size) * 
FROM Account.Customer  
WHERE Record_Id < @firstPageRecordId
ORDER BY Record_Id DESC;
```

A keyset driven solution can seek straight to the last position and then range scans the next/previous page, using the clustered index key position. The paging logic (state) must remember the last and first keys on the page being displayed in order to continue from there, instead of remembering the page number.

Rowcount based solutions (as well as LIMIT in MySQL) are less efficient than keyset based ones because they always have to count the records to position themselves, instead of seeking straight to the position as keysets can.

Comment: But the Record_Id can be 1, 3 , 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17.  The pages will not be equal, also the last page probably will not cover the whole table.

In this case, how to get accurate @lastPageRecordId?  
Just now I got it you want to enhance performance using Record_Id index, so you want me to alter the WITH clause and use Record_Id instead of Row_Number, I am not sure how to alter the WITH clause yet!! Am I following you?

Comment: Say you want to display pages of 3. First time you say TOP(3)... ORDER BY RecordId and you get 1,3,7. For next page you ask for TOP(3).. WHERE RecordId>7 ...ORDER BY ... and you get 10,11,12. To go down you ask for TOP(3) ... WHERE RecordId < 10 ... ORDER BY ... DESC and you get again 7,3,1. To go next you ask for TOP(3) ... WHERE RecordId > 12 ... ORDER BY... and you get 13,17. You use the first and last RecordId on the page as *keys*, not as ranks.

Comment: @Remus Hi, so is the keyset solution quicker than paging? Ive tried to create a stored stored procedure based on ur code above but i get no results returned. Any ideas?

Create Proc PagingSample
 ((at)Page_Size int,
 (at)firstPageRecordId int)
AS
begin
 SELECT top((at)Page_Size) * 
 FROM dbo.data  
 WHERE (at)(at)IDENTITY < (at)firstPageRecordId
 ORDER BY DateTime DESC;
end

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware that this was also called "keyset driven solutions". I've heard people call this the [seek method, as I described in a recent blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/). Anyway, great to see this being suggested. This happens rarely

Comment: "nobody cares about the performance of a cold cache". It surely depends how often its an outcome for a user. If your system runs hot then what you say is true but if its cold to mild in terms of what is in the cache and what a given user wants to read then the cold read is going to a relatively common use-case and matters. At the very least, in terms of sales and initial customer perception, the cold read can matter unless your init specifically warms. In scenarios where big integration jobs are going to pressure the cache, cold reads can then occur more often.

Answer (score 2):

I use this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_PagedItems
    (
     @Page int,
     @RecsPerPage int
    )
AS

-- We don't want to return the # of rows inserted
-- into our temporary table, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON


--Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TempItems
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(50),
    Price currency
)


-- Insert the rows from tblItems into the temp. table
INSERT INTO #TempItems (Name, Price)
SELECT Name,Price FROM tblItem ORDER BY Price

-- Find out the first and last record we want
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
SELECT @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SELECT @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1)

-- Now, return the set of paged records, plus, an indiciation of we
-- have more records or not!
SELECT *,
       MoreRecords =
    (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM #TempItems TI
     WHERE TI.ID >= @LastRec
    )
FROM #TempItems
WHERE ID > @FirstRec AND ID < @LastRec


-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using SQL Server 2012 - a new feature was added in the ORDER BY clause, to query optimization of a set data, making work easier with data paging for anyone who writes in T-SQL as well for the entire Execution Plan in SQL Server. Reference [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx).