# sql Fetch records from sql server database table in parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch records from a table in my sql server database in parts. Like, in one query I want to see first 1000 records, in next query next 1000 records. Likewise..

Is it possible with sql server ? I am using sql server 2008. While googling, I found `LIMIT` clause for `mysql`, but it does not work for `sql server`. So can any one give in Sql. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 1000 records:

```
SELECT  TOP 1000 *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        mycolumn
```

General solution (supports offset)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
ORDER BY
        mycolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Have also a look at [T-sql: how to perform optimised Paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214276/t-sql-how-to-perform-optimised-paging)