# convert LIMIT to TOP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

in MySQL we use `LIMIT` and in sql server we must use `TOP` instead of `LIMIT`,but we can use `LIMIT` in the this way:

`Limit X, Y` which X is the starting point and Y is duration.

now how can i use `TOP` like that example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: tnx @Mithun , your comments really helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ROW_NUMBER() function , with CTE (Common table Expression)

[ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
with cte as(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1) as rownumber from <table>)
select * from cte where rownumber between x and y
```

Comment: @gbn Yeah, my bad. Carry on as you were :) +1 to the answer.

Comment: @Fluffeh: The question is - equivalent of limit x,y in sql server

Answer (score 3):

You can't before SQL Server 2012 which added [FETCH..OFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx)

So you need to "page" using ROW_NUMBER function. Examples:

- [Is there any performance issue using Row_Number to implement table paging in Sql Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308220/27535)
- [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2135418/27535)

Comment: Even in SQL Server 2000 wouldn't this work?  `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC) AS data ORDER BY id ASC`  Perhaps not recommended in the case of other options, but at least it exists...

Comment: @Dems: yes. I assumed that folk would be on SS 2005 at least. In 2012 ;-)