# how to select first non-duplicate data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table(Id, Name, Type) in sql.

```
Id, Name, Type:
1, AA, 1
2, BB, 2
3, CC, 4
4, DD, 2
5, EE, 3
6, FF, 3
```

I want select the first non-duplicate data. Result:

```
Id, Name, Type:
1, AA, 1
2, BB, 2
3, CC, 4
6, FF, 3
```

I use DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but not working, I have select all row not select Type with DISTINCT or GROUP BY.

```
select DISTINCT Type
from tbltest
```

Comment: So you want to remove duplicate `Type`s and first means according to the ID?

Comment: I want select with non-duplicate 'Type' and order by 'Id'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like CTE's and `ROW_NUMBER` since it allows to change it easily to delete the duplicates.

Presuming that you want to remove duplicate `Type`s and first means according to the ID:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT Id, Name, Type,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY ID )
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
SELECT Id, Name, Type FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @user3933292: yes, it is efficient unless the data is not extremely large (so billions of records). http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309247/284240 Of course you need to use proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways.  My preference is `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, type
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by id) as seqnum
      from tbltest t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Performance of the above should be reasonable.  However, the following might be faster with an index on `type, id`:

```
selct id, name, type
from tbltest t
where not exists (select 1 from tbltest t2 where t2.type = t.type and t2.id < t.id);
```

That is, select the rows that have no lower `id` for the same `type`.