# dSQL Server paging large dataset with multiple tbl joins

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, paging

Currently I am *trying* to load a large **dataset** to a **gridview** which of course is timing out because the amount of rows being returned is so large. Instead of trying to page in the **gridview** via memory, how might I page on the server to prevent the timeout that occurs from loading the **dataset** all at once? I have tried using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445042/efficient-paging-with-large-tables-in-sql-2008), but the query still seems to hang. It may also be worth note that I have run my query against an execution plan and it has not suggested anything to consider. Please see my current implementation below:

```
with result_set as (select distinct row_number() over(order by a.date desc) as [row_number], a.date, vw.Name, a.accountNum,
a.action, z.loc, b.name, a.col
from tbl1 as a
inner join tbl2 as b
on b.id= ch.id
inner join tbl3 as z
on a.zip= z.zip
inner join tbl4 as vw
on a.accountNum= vw.accountNum collate database_default
where a.col is not null
) select * from result_set where [row_number] between 1 and 20
```

Am I the victim of poor indexing on my part? Or is something else i missed? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: what is your sql server version?

Comment: @Sajeetharan V. 11.0.2100.60, Standard Edition